# Make a class that implements an interface without altering the class code

Tags: java, interface, aop

I want to make a class Toto that implements interface Titi. The common way is:

```
public class Toto implements Titi
```

The problem is I am autogenerating the class Toto and it 's not practical to add everytime implements Titi. Is there a way to make it implement interface in Java EE 6. (like AOP for example)
and give me an example please

Comment: For AOP you could use Spring.

Comment: Subclass it in your code and add what you need.

Comment: In other words, don't use the generated class directly; subclass it with the additional functionality you need. I used to do this a lot with Hibernate classes, although composition is another approach, arguably a better one.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is impractical.  Having your code generator add an "implements Titi"?

Comment: @LouisWasserman : the generated code is in target and not commited in git. it s not practical to ask my team individually to add implements Titi.

Comment: He said have your code generator add it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of solutions. Without knowing the nature of your code generation it's difficult to help beyond generalities. AOP seems way overkill, though.

1. Change the template that generates your source, or use its the source gen's functionality
2. Alter the source post-generation.
3. Use a subclass or composite in your source.

**1.** If you can, change the templates. Most generators are aware that the source they generate may not fit precisely with your needs and allow either code insertion or signature modification. Even if it isn't super-easy, most have templates you can pull out of the classpath and repackage, even.

**2.** Simple search-and-replace could alter the code signature, and you can stuff your own implementation at the end of the generated class. This should be integrated into your build process.

**3.** My go-to choice would be to either composite the generated class into your own class, or subclass it if it makes sense to do that. This is super, super easy, and requires only trivial, automatable changes. I might also change the name of the generated class.

In other words, you have a class `Toto` with some generated methods, say `someMethod`:

```
public class Toto {
    public void someMethod() { ... }
}
```

Create a new, well-named class, that either subclasses this, or composites in, respectively:

```
public class TotoSubclass extends Toto implements Titi {
    // Titi implementation
}

public class TotoComposite implements Titi {
    private Toto toto;
    public TotoComposite(Toto toto) { this.toto = toto; }
    // Titi implementation
    // Toto delegates, IDEs can generate.
}
```

For some types of problems I wouldn't complain about extending `Toto` in this way, e.g., for a DAO it might make sense to just tack on the additional functionality. Inheritance can be a pain in some (most?) situations, and compositing might be safer. IDEs can generate the delegated methods, or you can use byte-code manipulation (e.g., Lombok) to auto-generate the delegates, but using the IDE is more general-purpose.